# Still got a GET 404 NOT FOUND in console

Tags: node.js, ejs

I deployed an Node JS app and I got a problem when it has to show an image

I get

> GET https://pedigree-notes.com/countryflags/united-states-of-america.png 404 (Not Found)

but in my app.js  I used theese.

```
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'images')));
app.use('/countryflags', express.static(path.join(__dirname,'countryflags')));
```

for /images is working, but for this is not working, can you please tell me what to do?

this is the ejs and the html tag where I use that 'flag'

```
 <td> <img src="/<%= recentNote.flag %>" alt="" style="width:20px"></td>
```

By adding that app.use(....) I expected to work, but it's not working.

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you move both folders under a common static assets folder e.g. `/public`, that way you can have a single static route

Comment: where in your file system is the `united-states-of-america.png` file?  And what is the value of `__dirname`?